# postman `Accept-Encoding`. How to disable decompression on the client

Tags: api, postman, response-headers

As i understand `Accept-Encoding` in header compresses the data retrieved and decompressed in the client(postman). Is it possible to avoid decompression(ie as a zip file)

I have the `Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br` in the header for a GET request i run from postman. the actual response is a csv file and the content of csv is shown in response. How do I get the response as a zip file when called from postman. (without modifying the API to compress). I want it zipped for reducing size when again passing the file.

`Content-Dispoistion:attachment` also not helps

Comment: try with this Accept-Encoding=gzip